# catchfilebetweentags bug with \verb command

Tags: verbatim, catchfile

With example

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
%<*example>
\verb|This is an example|
%</example>
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\CatchFileBetweenTags{\test}{main.tex}{example}
\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

I get output:

```
! LaTeX Error: \verb ended by end of line.
```

Everything else is working properly. If I copy/paste the piece of code directly in the `main.tex` file it works properly.

Comment: the catch commands take a fragment of the file and pass them as an argument of a macro, it is a documented restriction that `\verb` doesn't work in the argument of another command,

Answer (score 2):

The `\verb` command works only if the the argument is not already tokenized. The classical situation this shows up in is that you cannot use `\verb` in the argument of another command. However, the same problem applies here: to save the input to a macro, the 'caught' information has to be tokenized. That can't work, I'm afraid.